# CardView still shows a shadowed border even with cardElevation set to 0dp?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-cardview

I don't really have much hope for this widget (`CardView`). It is surely some kind of bug they made and to fix it we need to put some real effort in. If the `cardBackgroundColor` is not transparent, everything seems to look fine (there is not any border as well as the shadow, although it may be still a little visible but not very sensitive to your eyes).

Now if I set the `cardBackgroundColor` to transparent (`@android:color/transparent`) I can see the trace with shadow around the `CardView`.

I know using the `CardView` with this style (transparent background with no border and shadow) is a little strange, but the style may change by some settings, so it should be used at first.

Here is the code (mainly for the `CardView` which causes the undesired effect):

```
<!-- ra is namespace at http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ra:cardElevation="0dp"          
      ra:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
  >
```

Here is the screenshot showing what's wrong with this `CardView`:

[image]

The first image is what I want. The second one is what looking fine if the background is not transparent (white). The last one is the failed image showing some kind of bug as I mentioned.

I wonder if I may have to switch to using some other layout (and if any requirement to support shadow comes, I have to switch to using `CardView`, which spends my time changing the code, not very conveniently).

Comment: You did not upload your image. Also, I would suggest to look into Card style to see all the styles it have.

Comment: @jonathanrz thanks, there are not many attributes, the most suitable one is `cardElevation` and I already set it to `0dp`.

Comment: you already tried to create a FrameLayout and add CardView styles? I am not pretty sure what everything CardView does, but you are trying to force CardView to not work as a CardView, maybe this is just not possible. Not a real solution, but maybe the only way will be to have two views (one CardView and another normal) and change the visible one as you need.

Comment: @jonathanrz what do you mean by using a `FrameLayout` and add `CardView` style? do you mean I need to apply the `CardView` style myself (without the convenience of using `cardElevation`) if I need the shadow? Well if there is not any way to fix this bug, maybe I have to follow that approach.

Comment: I am not sure if this work, if all the CardView customization are made throught styles, it will work. But if it has more tasks done by the class than I believe that your only option is to have two distinct views and change the visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, with the elevation showing despite having `card_view:cardElevation="0dp"` in the CardView layout when the background is transparent. This was when CardView was being used with RecyclerView.

What did solve the problem for me was adding `card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"` to the layout.